# Table View is not reloaded after dismissing edit mode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sqlite

I'm trying to add new row to TableView with edit mode. Used [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html). But after dismissing my edit mode view my table view is not reloaded. My addItem: method

```
- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender {

    BIDAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BIDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    sqlite3 *database;
    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString *databasePath;

    databaseName = @"TestProjectDatabase.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(!success) {
        databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:databaseName ofType:nil];
    }

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into \"MyItems\" ( \"MyItemName\", \"MyItemDescription\") values ( '%@', '%@');", _nameTextField.text, _descriptionTextField.text];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database)); 
        }else{
            if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                //   NSLog(@"All ok");
            } else {
                //   NSLog(@"FAIL");
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

    MyItems *itemsToDatabase = [[MyItems alloc] initWithItemName:_nameTextField.text andItemDescription:_descriptionTextField.text];
    [appDelegate.myItems addObject:itemsToDatabase];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

SQL insertion is OK because where is new row after restarting my project. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table data source reads from appDelegate.myItems, you just need to reload the table itself `[tableView reloadData];`.

Comment: I thought about it. But in which method I need to add `[tableView reloadData];`?